# React Component doesn't receive new props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my App component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log("nextProps===>", nextProps);
  }
  clickHandler() {
    const { isLoading, request } = this.props;
    request();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <span>
        <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>Request</button>
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is how I rendering it:

```
let isLoading = false;
const request = function() {
  isLoading = true;
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App isLoading={isLoading} request={request} />,
  document.querySelector("#app")
);
```

When user click button, the `isLoaing` variable will change. however, the `<App />` seems doesn't receive it, because the `componentWillReceiveProps` doesn't call

Why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though your Prop isLoading is updating, there is nothing that will trigger a re-render of

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App isLoading={isLoading} request={request} />,
  document.querySelector("#app")
);
```

and since  `ReactDOM.render` isn't called again, the new prop is not received in `App` component

You might as well write a parent of App that receives the isLoading props and re-renders like

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
   state = {
      isLoading: false
   }
   request = () => {
      this.setState({ isLoading:true });
   }
   render() {
      return <App isLoading={isLoading} request={request} />
   }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.querySelector("#app")
);
```